# Rails - is there a better way to write this? looking for refactor advice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my limited knowledge I dont know how to write this without passing the volunteer as an argument to the status method.  Which normally wouldnt be an issue, except when I need all irregular volunteers.  Then I have to loop through Volunteers.all and evaluate each against the status method.  I feel like the overhead here is too great.

```
Class Volunteer < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :reports

  def status(volunteer)
    case
    when volunteer.reports.nought.where(:report_month => Report_range.months(6)).count > 5
        return 'inactive'
    when volunteer.reports.nought.where(:report_month => Report_range.months(6)).count >= 3
        return 'irregular'
    else
        return 'active'
    end
  end
end


class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :volunteer
  scope :nought, -> {where("hours IS NULL") || where("hours: 0")}
end

module Report_range
  def self.months(range)
   Volunteer.first.reports.order("report_month desc").limit(range).pluck(:report_month)
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance for helping a noob!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
class Volunteer < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :reports

  def status
    if number_of_recent_nought_reports > 5
      'inactice'
    elsif number_of_recent_nought_reports >= 3
      'irregular'
    else
      'active'
    end
  end

  private

  def number_of_recent_nought_reports
    # You could move the where call to scope in your `Report` class.
    @recent_nought_reports ||= reports.nought.where(:report_month => Report_range.months(6)).count
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the great response, on a side note: is it possible to use this method like a scope? for example: Volunteer.irregular?

Comment: @greyoxide yes `def irregular? status == 'irregular' end`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def status(volunteer)
  case
  when volunteer.reports.nought.where(:report_month => Report_range.months(6)).count > 5
    return 'inactive'
  when volunteer.reports.nought.where(:report_month => Report_range.months(6)).count >= 3
    return 'irregular'
  else
    return 'active'
  end
end
```

You don't need to pass the volunteer because you are calling the method status on an instance of Volunteer that already has direct access to reports. So the above becomes:

```
def status
  case
  when reports.nought.where(:report_month => Report_range.months(6)).count > 5
    return 'inactive'
  when reports.nought.where(:report_month => Report_range.months(6)).count >= 3
    return 'irregular'
  else
    return 'active'
  end
end
```

Additionally, you are running the count query two times which is not optimal. I suggest:

```
def status
  number_of_reports = reports.nought.where(:report_month => Report_range.months(6)).count
  case
  when number_of_reports > 5
    return 'inactive'
  when  number_of_reports >= 3
    return 'irregular'
  else
    return 'active'
  end
end
```

Finally the case returns the matching value so you don't need the returns.

```
def status
  number_of_reports = reports.nought.where(:report_month => Report_range.months(6)).count
  case
  when number_of_reports > 5
    'inactive'
  when  number_of_reports >= 3
    'irregular'
  else
    'active'
  end
end
```

There is more but that is a start.

Answer (score 1):

You could also specify it as using @Magnuss' code as a base point

```
class Volunteer < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :reports

  STATUSES = {(0..2) => 'active', (3..5) => 'irregular'}

  def status
    STATUSES.find(->{['inactive']}){|range,_| range === number_of_recent_nought_reports}.pop 
  end

  private

   def number_of_recent_nought_reports
     # You could move the where call to scope in your `Report` class.
     @recent_nought_reports ||= reports.nought.last_n_months(6).count
  end
end

class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :volunteer
  scope :nought, -> {where("hours IS NULL") || where("hours: 0")}
  scope :last_n_months, ->(months){ where(:report_month => Report_range.months(months)) }
end
```

This allows more flexibility in my opinion for adding more statuses by just redefining `STATUSES` as you see fit.

What this does is find the first result where the `number_of_recent_nought_reports` is in a range defined in `STATUSES` in the event that it falls outside of any of the ranges `['inactive']` is returned then `pop` pulls out just the status.

I also moved the report_month scope to `Report` as `last_n_months`.

Answer (score 0):

You could write:

```
def status(volunteer)
  case volunteer.reports
                .nought
                .where(:report_month => Report_range.months(6))
                .count
  when (6..Float::INFINITY) then 'inactive'
  when (3..5)               then 'irregular'
  else                           'active'
end
```